# Subprocess in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I want the output of the jobs command run in the shell as a string in python.

I have this code

```
import subprocess
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['jobs'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print  p1.communicate()
```

But this doesnt seem to work. The output I get is -

```
('', None)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Which Python version and OS are you on?  It works fine on Linux, Python 2.5.2.

Comment: What is the value of `p1.returncode`? (Btw., you don't need `shell=True`.)

Comment: I believe you are testing different code (the print statement as shown will output a string, not a tuple). Maybe there are other differences besides the print statement, which cause trouble. The code as shown works for me (Linux, Python 2.7.3).

Comment: i copied out the wrong block of code :P.... 
changed it now though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
In [5]: import subprocess

In [6]: output = subprocess.check_output("ps")

In [7]: print output
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 2314 pts/2    00:00:06 bash
 4084 pts/2    00:00:03 mpdas
 7315 pts/2    00:00:02 python
 7399 pts/2    00:00:00 ps


In [8]:
```

**Your code works fine for me.**

```
In [11]: import subprocess

In [12]: p1 = subprocess.Popen(['ps'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

In [13]: print  p1.communicate()[0]
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 2314 pts/2    00:00:06 bash
 4084 pts/2    00:00:03 mpdas
 7315 pts/2    00:00:02 python
 7682 pts/2    00:00:00 ps


In [14]:
```